# In a few species such as dicarbon (shown below) why are the pi bonding orbitals of lower energy than the sigma bonding orbitals?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

[image]

Normally the pi bonding orbitals are of higher energy because pi orbitals experience less direct overlap than sigma orbitals however in a few species this is not the case and I could not find any websites directly addressing this topic.

Comment: The molecule $\ce{C2}$ is extremely instable. To my knowledge, it only exists in the famous blue cone to be seen in the Bunsen flame. Its lifetime should probably be less than one millisecond. I would be pleased to know how and who somebody has decided that the first pi level is lower than the first sigma level. Is it not a mistake ?

Comment: I should note that dicarbon is in fact very unstable but this pehnomenon is observed in a few other species such as N2 as well.

Comment: How to justify that the first pi level is lower than the sigma bond made with 2p orbitals ?

Comment: C2 is a very weird molecule. I don't think all theoreticians agree how does it really bond.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/594/bonding-in-diatomic-c2-a-carbon-carbon-quadruple-bond

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/85223/in-c2-molecule-both-bonds-of-the-double-bond-are-pi-bonds-but-isnt-the-rule-t https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/32552/9961